# Is there a way to randomize the order of how a batch file runs the code?

Tags: batch-file

For a small project I am working on, I need to randomize how the code runs. I currently have the tasks separated by tags. i.e

:1_1

:1_2

etc.

Is there a way that I can use the goto command to be randomized?
If not, is there a better way that I can set this up?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: They are officially called labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /a maxtask=5
set /a task=%random% %% maxtask + 1
goto 1_%task%
```

will one one random task 1..5

You'd need to expand your question if this is insufficient.

Comment: This is perfect! I apologize for the somewhat confusing question. I am new to batch, and this site. Thanks for the help!